# A full answer is just converted to comment

Tags: support

I've just made an answer to [the question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43881/how-to-make-raspberrypi-always-mount-the-flash-drive-to-the-same-mount-point/43882#43882), and referred to the proper tutorial that shows how to do exactly what the asker wants to do. I was not plagiarising a tutorial, but briefly described all the parts involved. What is the problem with my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of reasons:

- By the scope defined in [the help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), general purpose linux questions are off-topic.  In practice this is treated as bit of a gray area, [as I have discussed elsewhere](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/732/5538).
- Here's [another meta Q&A more specifically about "Raspbian"](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/622/5538), although it is pretty clear what is really meant is general linux questions.  In my answer there, I explain that part of the problem is that we do not have expertise in sufficient volume for us to field all such questions and ignore the existence of [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), just as we do not have expertise in sufficient volume to ignore the existence of the larger [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  Answering this question in the way it was answered does *not* provide anything hopeful in this sense, as I will try to explain.
- If that question were migrated to U&L, it would be closed as a duplicate because it is something which has been dealt with many times in many places, *as your response indicates*.
- It's worth noting that **there's [already at least one exact duplicate *here*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/22960/5538)** with more information in it, so there are multiple reasons for this to have been closed.
- In cases like this, it is fine to give someone a quick link and explain this is well documented and easily researched topic *if you know what to search for*.  This is all your "answer" was, so I converted it to a comment and closed the question.

There is no need of anything more than that and looking at the final comment, it seems the O.P. is happy.

If the question were one which was more unusual (e.g., because it involved more particularly unique aspects of the pi) **and** one which *has not* been sufficiently dealt with elsewhere online **and** someone was willing to do it here, then great.

**We have a lot of questions that go unanswered because they do fall into this latter category.**  If people have time to answer questions, it would be much better if they make an effort to research and answer those as best they can rather than cherry picking things quickly -- this just leads to exploiting the system in a mostly unhelpful way, which is why it is also frowned upon on, e.g., our parent site Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought that a workflow would be different : answer a question first, and then migrate it to a proper/more-relevant part of the SE network, like a Linux or Raspbian one

Comment: Migration can only be done by mods; [see here](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5538+migrate) for some of my observations and opinions about that -- I close as "off-topic" much more often than I migrate for various reasons.  In any case, when it happens it depends on how the cookie crumbles.  It is possible that I or another mod may look at a "gray" question and leave it for a period of time to see what happens; this is one way of evaluating where our expertise potential currently is.  In any case, any answers are migrated *with* the question, they are not lost.

Comment: by the way - check the asker's comment on that question on my answer ;) It worked!

Comment: Yes, I said that in the original answer here, first statement after the list.  The fact that a comment is helpful does not turn it into an answer or make a question magically on-topic, if that is why you are pointing this out.  The final state of the Q&A seems to be fine.